# Xamarin listview image bind

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I use realmdb in my project and I store the data that the user added to the basket in the local memory. But I have a problem. One of the data I have stored is image. I can show all data in listview, but I cannot show the image in listview.
Why is the image not showing in listview? How can I show the image

With this code block, I save the data to realm db.

```
var realmDB = Realm.GetInstance();
            var myOrderRealm = realmDB.All<OrderOnRealm>().ToList();

            var maxOrderId = 0;
            if (myOrderRealm.Count != 0)
            {
                maxOrderId = myOrderRealm.Max(m => m.OrderId) + 1;
            }
            var Order = new OrderOnRealm
            {
                OrderId = maxOrderId,
                OrderImage = Convert.ToString(imgImage.Source),
                OrderName = lblName.Text,
                OrderCount = lblStepperValue.Text,
                OrderDetail = edtDetail.Text,
                OrderPrice = lblPriceNormal.Text
            };
            realmDB.Write(() =>
            {
                realmDB.Add(Order);
            });
            var orderList = realmDB.All<OrderOnRealm>().ToList();
```

I also display the data in this listview.

```
<ListView x:Name="lstOrder" ItemTapped="lstOrder_ItemTapped" HasUnevenRows="True">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>

                            <ViewCell>

                                <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                                    <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>

                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                            <RowDefinition/>

                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <Grid Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent">

                                            <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding OrderImage}"/>

                                        </Grid>

                                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Padding="8">

                                            <Grid RowSpacing="20">

                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition/>

                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding OrderName}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18" TextColor="Black" VerticalTextAlignment="End"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding OrderCount}" TextColor="Black" Opacity="0.8" FontSize="15"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding OrderDetail}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" TextColor="Black" Opacity="0.8" VerticalTextAlignment="End" FontSize="12" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
                                                <BoxView Grid.Row="3" BackgroundColor="#ef7860" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" WidthRequest="60"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding OrderPrice}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" TextColor="Black" Opacity="0.8"/>

                                            </Grid>

                                        </Grid>

                                    </Grid>

                                </Grid>

                            </ViewCell>

                        </DataTemplate>

                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                </ListView>
```

And this is my model.

```
public class OrderOnRealm : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string OrderImage { get; set; }
    public string OrderName { get; set; }
    public string OrderCount { get; set; }
    public string OrderDetail { get; set; }
    public string OrderPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks already for your help...

Comment: this is not valid `OrderImage = Convert.ToString(imgImage.Source),`

Comment: OrderImage = imgImage.Source,  I get an error when I write this way. How should I do?

Comment: you can't really get the image data *from* an Image control.  You need to get the data from the original source that was used to create the ImageSource

Comment: So how should I study

Comment: I have no idea how you are originally getting the data for `imgImage`

Comment: I write the original image with a parameter from another page.

Comment: is it from a locally downloaded image file?  An http url?  A stream?  The device camera?

Comment: A downloaded image file. In my solution file

Comment: if you want to store the image data in Realm, then read the data from the local file.  I assume Realm can store binary data, if not then you can encode it as Base64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get image from Resource Drawable, then store image in Realm database, you can set image in drawable as AndroidResource.

Changing the following code,  you will get the path like ***File:a11.jpg*** using following code.

```
 OrderImage = Convert.ToString(imgImage.Source),
```

using `OrderImage = (image1.Source as FileImageSource).File` to get correct image source

This is my sample that you can take a look:

```
<Image
            x:Name="image1"
            HeightRequest="50"
            Source="a11.jpg"
            WidthRequest="50" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btnadd"
            Clicked="btnadd_Clicked"
            Text="add image " />

        <Button
            x:Name="btnload"
            Clicked="btnload_Clicked"
            Text="load image" />

        <ListView x:Name="listview1" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding OrderName}" />
                            <Image
                                HeightRequest="50"
                                Source="{Binding OrderImage}"
                                WidthRequest="50" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

 public partial class Page32 : ContentPage
{
    public List<OrderOnRealm> orders { get; set; }
    public Page32()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
                        
    }

    private void btnadd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var realmdb = Realm.GetInstance();

        var myOrderRealm = realmdb.All<OrderOnRealm>().ToList();

        var maxOrderId = 0;
        if (myOrderRealm.Count != 0)
        {
            maxOrderId = myOrderRealm.Max(m => m.OrderId) + 1;
        }
        OrderOnRealm item = new OrderOnRealm()
        {
            OrderId = maxOrderId, OrderName = "image " + maxOrderId, OrderImage = (image1.Source as FileImageSource).File
        
        };
        realmdb.Write(() => {
            realmdb.Add(item);
        
        } );
    }
    private void loaddata()
    {
        var realm = Realm.GetInstance();
        orders = realm.All<OrderOnRealm>().ToList();
        listview1.ItemsSource = orders;
    }

   
    private void btnload_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loaddata();
    }
}
```